# How Indoor Navigation works in iOS using iBeacon or wi-fi?

Tags: ios, iphone, ibeacon, indoor-positioning-system

I am working on a project that has a requirement of Indoor navigations. Have been searching a lot, i only found some paid sdk's and other tools. I just want to know how exactly the indoor navigation works and what is the architecture used? Also I want to know how ibeacon can be used for indoor navigation. The implementation of Indoor navigations is required only for iOS device. Please let me know. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something other than programming.

Comment: Check out this WWDC 2014 video: Taking Core Location Indoors.

Comment: Please consider my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29091720/indoor-navigation-using-i-beacon-accuracy-is-changing-rapidly/29378983#29378983

Answer (score 8):

Indoor navigation with beacons or WiFi is a complex task for which you must be willing to lots of custom programming and surveying. Three main approaches are used.

The state of the art approach is to do signal fingerprinting from a number of WiFi or Bluetooth sources placed in the area.  A fingerprint specifies the expected signal level from each source at every possible point in the area.  From these fingerprints, a software model of the room must be generated which allows code to find the best matching coordinates in the map for the measured signal level from each source.

Performing the survey is very time consuming and must be redone if the transmitters are moved or if the room is rearranged.  For this reason, automation tools must be built to make it practical.

Several companies specialize in doing this work and have proprietary tools to set up new deployments.  Unfortunately, I know of no open source or off the shelf software to do this.

A simpler approach involves trilaterating between three or more reference signals.  But I have not heard any reports of this approach providing sufficient accuracy for a practical implementation, due to large variations in signal levels.  Calculated positions tend to drift by several meters when a device is standing still.

The third approach is simplest of all.  Place one beacon at each reference point.  And calculate the user position as being at whichever beacon is closest.  This is easy to do, but requires a large number of beacons.

Answer (score 2):

**Adding to the answer specified above as the third approach using trilateration in iBeacon indoor navigation**

An iOS device acting as a receiver of iBeacon signal gives a parameter called **accuracy** which is defined in Apple iOS programming docs as the accuracy of the proximity value, measured in meters from the beacon to the iOS device. Using this parameter we can form the mathematical model.

> **A head start to solution based on Trilateration and corresponding mathematical model can be found follwing the link  [iBeacon - Indoor Navigation](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/article/20141103102705-168695351-ibeacon-indoor-navigation)**