# Indoor Navigation using I-Beacon- Accuracy is changing rapidly

Tags: ios, ibeacon, indoor-positioning-system

I am doing an indoor navigation application using I-Beacon. For that i am using the accuracy given by the beacon. But it is changing rapidly. Since the value is changing, the X and Y coordinates of the user location, which has to be calculated is also varying even when i am static. So please help me to make the accuracy a constant when I m not moving.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Switch technologies.  It is close to impossible to accurately triangulate a position using iBeacons.  The rapidly changing values are primarily due to environment.  In an confined space you will be picking up echoes.  In a larger busy space then signals will be blocked or reflected by passers-by.  There will be variation cut to phone cases, location of the device (pocket, purse, held in the hand).  See the "moving core location indoors" from the WWDC 14 to see how Apple are tackling indoor positioning in iOS8.

Comment: Can you please give me the link of the video you mentioned ?

Comment: @AswinSathyan did you find any way to stable the distance which is beacons sending? i'm also spending lot of time on this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to read the following article about the experience with two positioning algorithms Trilateration and NonLinear Regression: [R/GA Tech Blog](http://techblog.rga.com/determining-indoor-position-using-ibeacon/)

You will find the complete iOS App that implements both algorithms from these guys on [GitHub](https://github.com/RGADigital/indoor_navigation_iBeacons/tree/show-work/ios/Group5iBeacons)

The App is very helpful to understand the difficulties of the requirement of the indoor navigation and experiment with it.

**Also please note:** Apple did announce the indoor positioning on WWDC 2014 with the Core Location Framework in iOS8, but after some couple of month they stopped the program. There were a lot of rush about the new feature. Apple decided than to offer the program only for big companies. You can register for it [here](https://mapsconnect.apple.com/?returnTo=%2Findoor).

It is important to understand the Apple strategy: The iBeacons technology is for proximity and advertising in contrast to Core Location Framework indoor positioning features in iOS8. The first one is just an addition to the second one, not replacement.

There is also an interesting article on the Estimote Blog  [about the physics of beacon tech.](http://blog.estimote.com/post/106913675010/how-do-beacons-work-the-physics-of-beacon-tech). The useful part for you begins with the sentence "When we started building it, we were experimenting with a method called trilateration."

Answer (score 1):

Indoor positioning using beacons is extremely hard, precisely due to the fluctuations in the distance (accuracy) estimates. You could try some averaging and smoothing out algorithms, but that's just the beginning to implementing reliable, beacon-based indoor positioning.

Estimote is working on ready-made library for indoor location with beacons: https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-Indoor-SDK, you might want to give it a try. It only works with Estimote beacons though.